# Does Flow work well on Apple Silicon M1 Macs?

Tags: react-native, shared-memory, flowtype, apple-m1

I'm getting this **Out of shared memory** on any React Native+Flow project that I try. This is the log message:

```
[2021-01-16 21:01:45.042] argv=/Users/hugo/Desktop/Admin MacBook/BeneTalk3/node_modules/flow-bin/flow-osx-v0.122.0/flow start --flowconfig-name .flowconfig --temp-dir /tmp/flow /Users/hugo/Desktop/Admin MacBook/BeneTalk3
[2021-01-16 21:01:45.042] lazy_mode=off
[2021-01-16 21:01:45.042] arch=classic
[2021-01-16 21:01:45.042] abstract_locations=off
[2021-01-16 21:01:45.042] max_workers=8
[2021-01-16 21:01:45.042] Failed to use anonymous memfd init
Out of shared memory:
Raised by primitive operation at file "src/heap/sharedMem.ml", line 43, characters 6-40
```

Works well on an intel Mac, but can't seem to get it working on the M1.

Answer (score 5):

This workaround seems to work for now:

https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/8538

```
[options]
sharedmemory.heap_size=3221225472
```